# Is there a (polyfill) code that resets all the inherited CSS properties on a given element?

Tags: javascript, css, html, polyfills

The subject says it all. Looking for a (polyfill) code that will reset all the inherited CSS properties on a given element (such as `<img>`, `<a>` or `<p>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use `HTML5` `boilerplate` or `css Reset` to reset all the inherited CSS properties.

check these articles  http://html5boilerplate.com/ ,

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/

Comment: I am looking for the code that will probably also be updated as soon as new properties are introduced for example. Does it seem logical that such a code exists (somewhere)?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to completely reset everything to the browser's default styling, then the modern CSS approach is to use the `revert` keyword with the `all` property:

```
all: revert;
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert),

> The **`revert`** CSS keyword rolls back the cascade so that the property takes on the value it would have had if there were no styles in the current style origin (author, user, or user-agent). In author stylesheets (the normal case), for the purposes of the given declaration, it's as if there were no author-level styles, thus resetting the property to the default value established by the user-agent stylesheet (or by user styles, if any exist).

*Caveat:* It is defined in the [CSS Cascading and Inheritance Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#default) working draft, so [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=revert) is currently limited to Safari only.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is create one of those elements but not attach it to the DOM. It wouldn't then receive any of the styles from your stylesheets. Then, using `window.getComputedStyle`, you will get a list of the default styles.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var s = window.getComputedStyle(a);

myTargetEl.style.color = s.color;  // or, use a loop to do all of them
```

Comment: thanks! what I am looking for is rather the code that will reset the inherited styles on the just shown element.

Comment: @BreakPhreak that should be what the code above does. The `s` variable contains all the default styles for an `<a>` tag. You can then apply it to whichever element(s) you want.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the `all` property, which sadly is not yet implemented by any browser other than Firefox.

Example:

```
h2 {
  all: initial; // Will reset any style set for h2 elements
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

Comment: The `all` property has better support than that now:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all

Still no IE or Safari at the time of this comment though

Comment: As of 2016: Safari is in, and MS Edge says "Development is likely for a future release" [(source)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/cssallshorthand)